# Issue with date_diff in PHP

Tags: php, datediff

I want to check expired date is before one month or not for that I have use below code

```
$expire_date = '2021-01-14 04:59:59';
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

$date1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$date2 = new DateTime($expire_date);
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

echo "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ".PHP_EOL; die(); // difference 0 years, 10 months, 8 days

if($interval->m > 1 && $interval->y <= 0){
    $status = "Yes"; // for expired
}else{
    $status = "No"; // not expired
}
```

with this case it is showing me wrong data so how can I find expire date before one month from the current date in PHP

Comment: why is this wrong? Please clarify: Are you trying to find whether the given date `$expire_date` is within 1 month from NOW?

Comment: The above outputs `difference 0 years, 10 months, 8 days` which results in `$status = Yes`

Comment: Why do you need `$interval->y <= 0`? There is also a `die` there.

Comment: `$interval->y > 0 || $interval->m > 1` IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to generate a date which is one month from now, and compare the expiry date with that. If it is less, then the expiry is within one month:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->modify('+1 month');
$date2 = new DateTime($expire_date);

if ($date2 < $now) {
    echo "expiry is in less than 1 month\n";
}
else {
    echo "expiry is more than 1 month away\n";
}
```